# Fatal error required once()

Tags: php, apache, xampp

i am getting this error when i run my project . even that i have file base.php in prpc folder .

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'prpc/base.php'
>   (include_path='C:\xampp\htdocs\web_www_root/cms-includes:C:\xampp\htdocs\web_www_root/cms-includes/pear:C:\xampp\htdocs\web_www_root/cms-includes/:.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR;C:\xampp\htdocs\web_www_root') in C:\xampp\htdocs\web_www_root\cms-includes\prpc\client2.php on line
>   3.

thanks to All . please give any suggestion

Comment: try with `../prpc/base.php` or `./prpc/base.php` or `/prpc/base.php` or full path

Comment: Anant i tried but did'nt work. any more please

Comment: yes when i tried full path then it solved my problem . thanks Mr Anant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try like below:-

```
../prpc/base.php
```

OR

```
 ./prpc/base.php
```

OR

```
 /prpc/base.php
```

OR

provide full path  like:-`require_once("C:/xampp/htdocs/web_www_root/cms-includes/prpc/base.php")`

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes relative path doesn't work.

You should provide full path to the file

```
require_once("C:\xampp\htdocs\web_www_root\cms-includes\prpc\base.php");
```

I,also had faced the similar issue.And above solution worked for me.Better,if you can give a try.